# Error: Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

```
void main() {
  Car c1 = new Car('E1001');
}

class Car {
  String engine;
  Car(String engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
    print("The engine is : ${engine}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ravi Setva's accepted answer helps in solving the query, but here is the explanation as to why exactly approaches 1 and 2 work:

1. **Allow Nullable**: By default, Dart is "Non-nullable", which means a variable cannot contain a `null` value unless it was initialized with `null` in the first place. This has the advantages of compiler optimizations by tagging something that cannot have null throughout the program lifetime.
   However, using `?` allows `null`s to be used by allowing it. So it is up to us to use this principle which Dart doesn't force on us.
2. **Lazy Initialization**: This is a concept that basically means that a variable can be initialized at an instant later to its declaration. This is achieved by using the `late` keyword during variable declaration. This is done for many complex reasons, of which the most simple reason one can think of is to prevent heavy operations right during the declaration of a variable to streamline and optimize performance and tag those for a later time when it actually is needed.

Comment: Perfect explanations,  Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

In the dart null-safety feature,

1. either make the engine variable nullable by `?`,

   ```
   class Car {
     String? engine;
     Car(String engine){
        this.engine = engine;
        print("The engine is : ${engine}");
     }
   }
   ```
2. or add the `late` keyword to initialise it lazily,

   ```
   class Car {
     late String engine;
     Car(String engine){
        this.engine = engine;
        print("The engine is : ${engine}");
     }
   }
   ```
3. or initialize the variable in the constructor's initialize block.

   ```
   class Car {
     String engine;
     Car(String engine) : engine = engine {
        print("The engine is : ${engine}");
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: or on more constructor: Car(this.engine);

Answer (score 0):

Update, for initialize the variable in the constructor's:

```
class Car{
    String name;
    int wights; 
    Car(this.name,this.wigths);
    Car.origin(): this.name='', this.wigths=0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using late keyword you can make a null variable.

Ex: late String engine;

"?" used for making null value.

Ex: String? engine;